# Kotlin DSL use multiple res folders for fonts

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

How can I set multiple font folders using Kotlin DSL in build gradle file?

I have tried this code:

```kotlin
android.sourceSets.getByName("main") {
    res.srcDirs(
        "/src/main/res",
        "/src/main/res/fonts/ano",
        "/src/main/res/fonts/roboto"
    )
}
```

[image]

Gradle is synced successfully, but I cannot get the fonts using `R.font.roboto_black`??

Comment: Did you tried cleaning the build?

Comment: Yes, I have tried "Build -> Rebuild project", also "Invalidate cash restart" and "Gradle -> Reload Gradle Project"

Comment: Also tried using the original "font" folder and adding subfolders inside it, but that did not worked either

Comment: How would it know that it's a `font` to appear as a member of `R.font`? Also wondering if this is you've seen documented, I can't find anything myself https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/font-resource

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is impossible to have nested folders directly inside the main "font" folder

Instead the solution is since we marked both dirs:  `/src/main/res/fonts/ano` and  `/src/main/res/fonts/roboto` as resource directories, to add "font" folder inside each res folder, so "../ano/font" and "../roboto/font" and this works, but is uglier solution.

[image]

So we will still use the same gradle solution, but add additional `font` folders
And then fonts are successfully recognized:

[image]

Comment: We can do the same for 'layout' for different screens, 'drawable' or any kind of resource